# Android GLES - Flame shader

Tags: android, glsl, shadertoy, gles

I'm quite starter of using GLES 2.0 on Android and I am trying to create a Flame-shaped shader using GLSL. I tried applying the shader from the following link:
https://www.shadertoy.com/view/MdKfDh

However, the result I got is not satisfactory.

[image: Flame Shader]

The image I created looks like the flames are flowing diagonally and the shape is too stretched vertically, while the flame shader on "[shadertoy](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/MdKfDh)" gives the impression of flames bursting out. The glsl fragment code I wrote is like this:

```
precision mediump float;

#define timeScale           iTime * 1.0
#define fireMovement        vec2(-0.01, -0.5)
#define distortionMovement  vec2(-0.01, -0.3)
#define normalStrength      40.0
#define distortionStrength  0.1

uniform vec2 screenSize;
uniform float progress;

// #define DEBUG_NORMAL

/** NOISE **/
float rand(vec2 co) {
    return fract(sin(dot(co.xy ,vec2(12.9898,78.233))) * 43758.5453);
}

vec2 hash( vec2 p ) {
    p = vec2( dot(p,vec2(127.1,311.7)),
    dot(p,vec2(269.5,183.3)) );

    return -1.0 + 2.0*fract(sin(p)*43758.5453123);
}

float noise( in vec2 p ) {
    const float K1 = 0.366025404; // (sqrt(3)-1)/2;
    const float K2 = 0.211324865; // (3-sqrt(3))/6;

    vec2 i = floor( p + (p.x+p.y)*K1 );

    vec2 a = p - i + (i.x+i.y)*K2;
    vec2 o = step(a.yx,a.xy);
    vec2 b = a - o + K2;
    vec2 c = a - 1.0 + 2.0*K2;

    vec3 h = max( 0.5-vec3(dot(a,a), dot(b,b), dot(c,c) ), 0.0 );

    vec3 n = h*h*h*h*vec3( dot(a,hash(i+0.0)), dot(b,hash(i+o)), dot(c,hash(i+1.0)));

    return dot( n, vec3(70.0) );
}

float fbm ( in vec2 p ) {
    float f = 0.0;
    mat2 m = mat2( 1.6,  1.2, -1.2,  1.6 );
    f  = 0.5000*noise(p); p = m*p;
    f += 0.2500*noise(p); p = m*p;
    f += 0.1250*noise(p); p = m*p;
    f += 0.0625*noise(p); p = m*p;
    f = 0.5 + 0.5 * f;
    return f;
}

/** DISTORTION **/
vec3 bumpMap(vec2 uv, vec2 resolution) {
    vec2 s = 1. / resolution;
    float p =  fbm(uv);
    float h1 = fbm(uv + s * vec2(1., 0));
    float v1 = fbm(uv + s * vec2(0, 1.));

    vec2 xy = (p - vec2(h1, v1)) * normalStrength;
    return vec3(xy + .5, 1.);
}

vec3 constructCampfire(vec2 resolution, vec2 normalized, float time) {
    vec3 normal = bumpMap(normalized * vec2(1.0, 0.3) + distortionMovement * time, resolution);

    vec2 displacement = clamp((normal.xy - .5) * distortionStrength, -1., 1.);
    normalized += displacement;

    vec2 uvT = (normalized * vec2(1.0, 0.5)) + time * fireMovement;
    float n = pow(fbm(8.0 * uvT), 1.0);

    float gradient = pow(1.0 - normalized.y, 2.0) * 5.;
    float finalNoise = n * gradient;
    return finalNoise * vec3(2.*n, 2.*n*n*n, n*n*n*n);
}

void main() {
    vec2 resolution = screenSize;
    vec2 normalized = gl_FragCoord.xy / resolution;
    vec3 campfire = constructCampfire(resolution, normalized, progress);
    gl_FragColor = vec4(campfire, 1.0);
}
```

As you can see, the GLSL code I wrote is very similar to the code in "[shadertoy](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/MdKfDh)". The difference is, I pass in the `screenSize`(pixels) and `progress`(float seconds) from the Android side. For your information, the code above is fragment shader, and I've already adjust vertex shader using `gl_Position` for entire screen. I am not sure why the result is not what I expected.

Also, I have another problem where after about 10 seconds, the image becomes pixelated and gradually turns into a square flame.

[image: Pixelated Flame shader]

It seems to be a problem when the `progress` value becomes too large, but I am not sure of the reason, and don't know how to fix it.

If anyone knows the cause and solution to these issues, I would greatly appreciate your response. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I can tell you that the issue is not with your shader code.  I took your shader code, placed it directly into ShaderToy, and exchanged the `progress` variable for the `iTime` variable, exchanged `gl_FragCoord.xy` for `fragCoord`, and exchanged `screenSize` for `iResolution.xy`.

Note, I also changed all references of `normalized` to `uv` to match the original.

Therefore, the issue must with the inputs not matching the ShaderToy inputs correctly.  I expect your `screensize` is being transferred wrong, as it looks like the screen is either providing rotated values, or has in some other way become compressed.

EDIT: Also, try changing you phone to landscape mode or making a free floating quad with the same aspect ratio as the example.  Because its using numerical noise, I expect the numbers have been chosen so they only work with a certain aspect ratio.  Landscape not Portrait.

Also, check to make sure you're passing in progress as a 0 sec -> X sec value rather than just a system clock call.

Otherwise, I can say that there are no errors in the code, and a reverse implementation back to ShaderToy works as expected.

My reimplementation of your Shader using ShaderToy with the structural changes can be found at:  https://www.shadertoy.com/view/ct3GDS

Comment: I'm so sorry for late reply :'(
After I ask that question, I was so busy to check it...
I appreciate your solution, and I think I can try it on next week.

Answer (score 1):

The noise function is broken for huge `progress` values (large displacement). It's suffering from precision loss, up to the point where you can see the surviving bits with your own eyes.

You'll need to somehow wrap `progress` around once exceeds 100 or so seconds. Given that your noise isn't tileable, you'll need to sample it twice with a modulo while wrapping around and lerp for the transition phase.

Comment: Yes, as you say huge `progress` value is the problem...
Yet, I couldn't understand about the `modulo` you mentioned, but I'll figure it out on next week, when I have free time  :'(
Sorry for late reply, and I appreciate your answer